# Java How to set Vector type from class type

Tags: java, vector

I have this code below (which is deserializing a class):

```
....
Type type = field.getGenericType();
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType ptype = (ParameterizedType) type;
if(c.getSimpleName().equals("Vector")){
    Class pta = (Class) ptype.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Vector<what to put here> v = (Vector)field.get(obj);
    if(v == null){
        v = new Vector<what to put here>();
        field.set(obj, v);
    }
....
```

My question is how do I change the Vector to take a certain type of data just from knowing the class name of what it took before (which would be the pta var)?

Comment: Doing Vector<pta.class> v = (Vector)field.get(obj); gives me the error "Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected"

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't work. I got it wrong somehow.

Comment: Seems this approach can't work, as you can't place dynamic expression between angle brackets, only compile-time-known expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics are resolved at compile time, so there is no way to do this as you have listed.  Just use a `Vector<Object>` or `Vector`

Comment: Generics don't work on primitive types, only their wrappers (int vs. Integer)

Comment: Is it possible of creating the vector via Class.forName() and somehow passing the type?

Comment: I would guess not.  Even if you could - why would you?  There's no way to reference the generic class from your code.

Comment: *Would Object work even if the vector was a primitive type* of course not. You cannot add a primitive to a `Vector`

Comment: So, when I do Vector<Object>, it thinks the object is a string (even though it should be a Point or Rectangle...or something else).

Comment: Well, it was my bad. I had a typo in an if statement..LOL. Well, so it works as Vector<Object>(). THANKS A BUNCH FOR ALL YOUR HELP!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `Vector` instead of `Vector<what to put here>` will work. Anyway on runtime the [generic erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) logic is used and your vector will not have a specified type anymore.

Regarding your comment related to the primitive type, note that you will not be even able to insert primitive types into an `Vector`. From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html): "The Vector class implements a growable array of objects". When you are adding primitives [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) is used to convert them into their object counter part.

Comment: Read above my comments from the other answers.

Comment: @ScottDeutsch When you are doing a `Vector` or `Vector<Object>` it's not interpreting your content as a string, it's an `Object`. If before your serialization you had `Vector<Point>`, after deserialization you will have a `Vector` or `Vector<Object>` (depending on how you will declare your variable), but the content will have `Point` objects.